# unconnected line (xx,yy) to (XX,YY) - Altium designer

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, altium, bus, architecture

Newbie in Altium designer here. I have read the online documentation from Altium, however, I still have a warning when trying to compile my schematic in Altium:

my schematic: [image]

The warning says: unconnected line (xx, yy) to (XX, YY) and refers to the right and lower part of the bus. Strangely it doesn't complain about the left part of the bus. I drew the bus at once, in other words, it is not composed of two or more parts.

[image]

I have tried multiple things like inter alia redrawing everything, but the warning keeps being showed.
How can I solve this issue?

**EDIT:**

This is my current schematic that still needs modifications: [http://www.imgur.com/a/Zy1nK](https://www.imgur.com/a/Zy1nK)

This is the schematic mine is based on http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?baseLiteratureNumber=spmu365&fileType=pdf (starts on page 36)

Comment: It's hard to tell because the screenshot is not pixel-perfect, but it looks like you may not be aligned to the grid in a lot of places.

Comment: @Daniel I get the same error even when I just put a bus for the upper part like so: http://imgur.com/a/MD5vV . Does this give any clue?

Comment: Considering that these are graphical buses with no function other than to look nice, what happens when you delete them?

Comment: @Daniel the warnings go away

Comment: Ignore it or delete the bus. You really need to clean up the way lines are crossing all over the place though. Honestly the bus is totally redundant, since virtually everything connects everywhere in your schematic. It's not like you're trying to differentiate between two different buses...

Comment: But I am trying to connect the pins of my microcontroller to my external pins of my board by using a bus comparable to this:http://goo.gl/YBKfIM Is a bus not better/cleaner for doing this in my case? The entire schematic, that still needs modifications: http://imgur.com/a/Zy1nK

Comment: @Daniel or are only net labels more than enough?

Comment: @Daniel BTW: this is the schematic I based mine on: http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?baseLiteratureNumber=spmu365&fileType=pdf (starts on p36). As you can see they use buses as well...

Comment: That schematic is really, really bad. Yes, in Altium, if you set net labels up as Global (as someone showed you in another question) you do not need the bus to have them connect. Again, in Altium, the only bus that matters is the "logical bus". This is a "graphical bus" and has no function -- it's just for schematic organization.

Comment: @Daniel how come it s so bad? This is straight from TI!

Comment: Some of the apps engineers there have only designed a handful of PCBs in their lives! Consider how you might draw it so that someone who isn't familiar with the design can get the idea as quickly as possible. Future you will thank present you.

Comment: Double bonus hint: see where you've mixed bus entries and sheet ports? Don't do that... either push the bus out so it doesn't run over the ports or put the ports elsewhere on the sheet.

Comment: If you are a newbie, please try a simpler schematic first. Get it right and then proceed to complex schematics, like the one above. I'm saying this because your alignment is off at a lot of places and that is the reason why there is a warning being shown.
Also, try to give adequate spacing between wires. Put them too close and you'll short them.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue labeling the bus, according with the lines it contains. E.g: your bus contains PF1, PF2, PF3, the label must be PF[1..3]